# Upload image and change default image location everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, image-uploading

I have an image in a div given below that appears on every page of my website and I have a URL link available to me that contains a profile picture. I would like to replace the image src attribute and update the profile picture and make sure that it updates on every other page. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this using javascript/jquery? Kindly let me know.

Test image URL: http://www.hdrspotting.com/images/default_profile.jpg

```
<div id="d2c-hey-user" class="d2c-user-panel" style="display: block;">
<img src="../images/defaultHeadshot_lg.png" style="display:none;" class="pacific-header-user-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Save the url in session storage.on every page try to access the url from session storage....

Comment: I highly recommend *not* asking how to do anything ever in a framework and devastatingly even less with jQuery. People who write *real* code and run circles around people who rely on frameworks and they get it done at a higher quality and without tacking on another 70KB of bandwidth. Good luck.

Comment: well I have the profile picture url information in my database for a particular user. All I need to do is replace that src location to that location for that user.